# Can't list file use it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPIllegalReplyException Java SE

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I have a trouble with FTPClient.lists(). Password and Username work properly in filezilla, but, if I try to connect use my code:

```
try {
        ftp.setMLSDPolicy(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTP);
        ftp.connect(host, port);
        ftp.login(un, pw);
        try {
            FTPFile l[] = ftp.list();
            for (FTPFile fTPFile : l) {
                System.out.println(fTPFile.getName());
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException | FTPIllegalReplyException | FTPException | FTPDataTransferException | FTPAbortedException | FTPListParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(testFTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("OKE");
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException | FTPIllegalReplyException | FTPException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(testFTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

with Exception error:

```
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPIllegalReplyException
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPCommunicationChannel.readFTPReply(FTPCommunicationChannel.java:201)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.openPassiveDataTransferChannel(FTPClient.java:3614)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.openDataTransferChannel(FTPClient.java:3549)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.list(FTPClient.java:2078)
    at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.list(FTPClient.java:2273)
    at rekon.Module.testFTP.listFiles(testFTP.java:53)
    at rekon.Module.testFTP.main(testFTP.java:67)
```

I have try username and password in filezilla app was work properly.

Comment: The exception has some message for sure, right? Show us!

Comment: thanks for comment, but I have write an exception above. I don't have any idea about message for detail.